# Solr search error when dealing with Arabic string

Tags: unicode, solr, utf-8, encode, arabic

I'm struggling with Solr search Arabic for several days and made some experiment. Here is the simple reflection of the problem.

After I store some Arabic sentence (now only 1 word السوري ) into database and have Solr index it, then query it by `q=*:*&wt=python`,(if no wt part, it was garbled chars) the response is:

```
'\u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u201e\u00d8\u00b3\u00d9\u02c6\u00d8\u00b1\u00d9\u0160'
```

The actual word I store there for index is coding in another way:

```
'\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb3\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x8a'
```

As you can tell, there is a one-to-to corresponding from `\xd8`↔`\u00d8`. But I don't know what is the name of this coding, thus I cannot convert it. And when I do the search as: `<>/select/?q=السوري&wt=python`,the response is:

```
{'responseHeader':{'status':0,'QTime':0,'params':{'wt':'python','q':u'\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0648\u0631\u064a'}},'response':{'numFound':0,'start':0,'docs':[]}}
```

No docs found and it seems using a third version for coding `u'\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0648\u0631\u064a'`. if I take it and `encode('utf8')` then it convert back to `'\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb3\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x8a'`.

In summary, when it (السوري) is in my code (python) or in data base (mysql),
it presents as 'form1':

```
'\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb3\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xd9\x8a'
```

When it is indexed by Solr, it converts to form2:

```
'\u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u201e\u00d8\u00b3\u00d9\u02c6\u00d8\u00b1\u00d9\u0160'
```

And when I use `<>/select/?q=السوري&wt=python`, to query from browser (Google chrome), it becomes form3:

```
'\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0648\u0631\u064a'
```

(which could convert back to form1 by `encode('utf8')` But since they are *different*, the search matches nothing.

Therefore, those three different encode strategy may be the core problem. Could anyone help me figure it out and solve the search problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Analyzer are you using?

Comment: The current schema.xml we are using to define arabic text is:    <fieldType name="text_arabic" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="arabic_stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

Comment: <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="arabic_stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

Comment: Could you give us further help here?

Comment: Hmm all that looks fine then. How are you indexing (i.e. how are you posting it to Solr) your data and what encoding is it in? Are you sure it is in UTF-8 and not a 16-bit version of Unicode?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That maybe the problem there. I use either the python urllib library to encode or use the google chrome directly with the q=لسوري, both produce the same problem.

Comment: If I enter q=*:*, it returns me as the 16-bit version of unicode. I think it indicates that internally, Solr store it as this kind of encoding (\u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u201e\u00d8\u00b3\u00d9\u02c6\u00d8\u00b1\u00d9\u0160)? But the "query processor" does not convert it with the same encoding as it stores?

Comment: Well Solr will store it however you post to it, so when you *create* the index, how are you doing it?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by how I create the index. I define the schema as above and in the data-config.xml as :<dataConfig>
        <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
   driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   url="jdbc:mysql://<IP>/<table>"
   user="root" 
   password="<pwd>"/>
        <document>
        <entity name="<table>" 
                query="select * from tivo_tags"
                deltaImportQuery="select * from <table> where ID='${dataimporter.delta.id}'"
                deltaQuery="select id from <table> where last_modified &gt; '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">

Comment: And then use the 'full-import' to have it indexed, is there anything I need to config there?

Comment: In the dataSource tag, try adding `encoding="UTF-8"`and then in the database URL, make it like this: `jdbc:mysql://<IP>/<table>?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8`. Finally, make sure that your data in the database is stored as UTF-8, or at least that if it converts the data to UTF-8 for the connection, it does so properly.